# Why I cannot call the object function from other class?

Tags: java, function, class, object, call

As the title mentioned.
Why the main class unable to call the event.java function and print out the message i want it to print? Is there anything I missing for that? Many Thanks.

App.java: (The main program)

```
package com.mainsystem;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
        System.out.println("Hi");
        Event event = new Event();
        event.StartGame();
    }

}
```

Event.java (Called by Main program)

```
package com.mainsystem;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Event {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void StartGame() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to new World.");
        System.out.println("You are now invited to this new world...");
    }


}
```

My Expecting Result:

```
Hi.
Welcome to new World.
You are now invited to this new world...
```

But the result showing now is:

```
Hi
```

Comment: Never mind, you are single threaded here - not the issue with "Main returning".

Comment: The code in your question produces your expected result when I run it. In other words, I cannot reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an exception thrown, when initiating your `Event-Class`? You are creating an instance of `PlayerReaction` and `Player` as well, maybe a NullPointer somewhere there inside?

For debugging purpose you could catch and print all exceptions that might appear somewhere:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Hi");
    try{
       Event event = new Event();
       event.StartGame();
    } catch (Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```